# Inequality operators fail when comparing variants

Tags: excel, vba

I've written an algorithm that sorts integer values in ascending order, but keeps corresponding info in adjacent cells sorted in-line with it. It uses Arr as a snapshot of the cell being sorted, builds an array of the values' indices (TagIndex) if they were sorted in ascending order, then applies TagIndex to that and the adjacent cells.

For example, it should take this...

```
----------------------------------
| 5/14/12  |  87  |  91  |  102  |
| 12/8/11  |  96  |  81  |  93   |
| 9/30/10  |  75  |  101 |  74   |
| 4/26/08  |  107 |  95  |  64   |
----------------------------------
```

...and sort by the second leftmost column to turn it into this:

```
----------------------------------
| 9/30/10  |  75  |  101 |  74   |
| 5/4/12   |  87  |  91  |  102  |
| 12/8/11  |  96  |  81  |  93   |
| 4/26/08  |  107 |  95  |  64   |
----------------------------------
```

Here's the code:

```
Dim cell as Range
Dim Arr, TempArr, BoundVal As Variant

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(targetColumn).DataBodyRange

    Arr = Split(cell.Value, Chr(10))
    ReDim TagIndex(0 To UBound(Arr)) As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        BoundVal = Arr(i) 'starts with first value and index
        TagIndex(i) = i   'as defaults
        For j = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            If Arr(j) < BoundVal Then  'if sorter finds a smaller value,
                BoundVal = Arr(j)      'flags it...
                TagIndex(i) = j        '...and its index as smaller,
            End If                     'keeps looking,
        Next j                         'leaves For loop with the smallest,
        Arr(TagIndex(i)) = 201         'and moves it up out of reach so sorter won't 
    Next i                             'flag it anymore (none of the values go above 200)

    For j = leftBoundColumn To rightBoundColumn 
        TempArr = Split(Cells(cell.Row, j).Value, Chr(10))
        For i = 0 To UBound(TempArr)
            Arr(i) = TempArr(TagIndex(i))
        Next i
        Cells(cell.Row, j).Value = Join(Arr, Chr(10))
    Next j

Next cell
```

This code worked dandy at first, but I had two separate versions - one for sorting integers and another for sorting dates - and wanted one that would handle both. To do that, I tried declaring BoundVal as a Variant in the new one. When the results went wonky, keen use of MsgBox'es revealed that it was failing logic tests at the < operator, trying to tell me No for 96<201 and Yes for 107<75 (but no for 117/107, like it should).

If I go back to declaring BoundVal as an Integer, it starts working fine for integers but gives me a Type Mismatch error when I try it on dates.

Is there some fundamental problem with comparing Arr(j) < BoundVal? Both are variants, both are descended from strings. Any ideas?

Comment: Just because you declare a variable to be variant does not mean that it stays just that at run-time. Just test it yourself: `Dim varTMP As Variant` then set it to 20 in the next line `varTMP = 20` and finally ask what type the variable is `Debug.Print TypeName(varTMP)`. You will get the answer `Integer`. So, maybe you want to include a few more TextBoxes to check what you are comparing to one another...

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem. But BoundVal = CVar(Arr(i)) isn't succeeding at changing BoundVal to a variant. How else might it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get away from all these `Variant` variables. This type (similar to declaring a variable as an `Object`) should be your very last resort. `Variant` can be anything and might even change in the course of the code (as shown above). So, if you are using them to compare them to something else then you might end up comparing a `Boolean` (TRUE or FALSE)  to a `Date` or a `String` or something else. VBA is there to enable you and take control! So, I'd recommend that you do just that.

Having said that and due to the fact that we are missing some code (obviously, the above code is incomplete as makes use of some variables which are neither declared nor initialized) here are some hints on how you can improve your code and possibly get to a working result yourself:

(1) If you want to declare multiple variables in one line then you still need to repeat the variable type for each variable. So, you need to write

```
Dim Arr as Variant, TempArr as Variant, BoundVal As Long
```

(2) Try to avoid `Variant` whenever possible and use the appropriate type instead. For example `BoundVal` seems to store whole numbers or dates and therefore the data type `Long` might be best.

(3) Arrays are normally (VBA default) ranging from 0 to ArrayCount - 1. So, the base is set to 0: `Option Base 0` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx Still, to make your code last longer (and more transparent) I'd include this line in your code and change your loops to

```
For j = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
```

instead of

```
For j = 0 To UBound(Arr)
```

(4) Force yourself to declare all variables to ensure that you know what's going on: `Option Explicit` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx

(5) Use `.Value2` whenever possible instead of `.Value` for a small speed bonus. Furthermore, this will essentially give you dates in form of a number only and not as a date².

After all of the above changes your code should look something like this:

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Sub tmpSO(Optional targetColumn As Long, Optional leftBoundColumn As Long, Optional rightBoundColumn As Long)

Dim cell As Range
Dim Arr As Variant, TempArr As Variant
Dim BoundVal As Long, TagIndex() As Long, i As Long, j As Long

'set the defaults for optional parameters
If targetColumn = 0 Then targetColumn = 2
If leftBoundColumn = 0 Then leftBoundColumn = 1
If rightBoundColumn = 0 Then rightBoundColumn = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns.Count

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(targetColumn).DataBodyRange

    Arr = Split(cell.Value2, Chr(10))
    ReDim TagIndex(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr))
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        'starts with first value and index, use default 0 if necessary
        If IsDate(Arr(i)) Then             'if the item can be interpreted as a date then
            BoundVal = CLng(CDate(Arr(i))) 'convert the string to a date and convert the date to a number
        Else                               'otherwise treat it as a number only
            BoundVal = CLng(IIf(IsNumeric(Arr(i)), Arr(i), 0))
        End If
        TagIndex(i) = i                    'as default
        For j = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            If CLng(IIf(IsDate(Arr(j)), CDate(Arr(j)), Arr(j))) < BoundVal Then      'if sorter finds a smaller value,
                BoundVal = CLng(IIf(IsDate(Arr(j)), CDate(Arr(j)), Arr(j)))          'flags it...
                TagIndex(i) = j            '...and its index as smaller,
            End If                         'keeps looking,
        Next j                             'leaves For loop with the smallest,
        Arr(TagIndex(i)) = 201             'and moves it up out of reach so sorter won't
    Next i                                 'flag it anymore (none of the values go above 200)

    For j = leftBoundColumn To rightBoundColumn
        TempArr = Split(Cells(cell.Row, j).Value, Chr(10))
        For i = 0 To UBound(TempArr)
            Arr(i) = TempArr(TagIndex(i))
        Next i
        Cells(cell.Row, j).Value2 = Join(Arr, Chr(10))
    Next j

Next cell

End Sub
```

Disclaimer: I know that this answer is not complete and that the above code probably needs some tweaking before it really does what you want it to do. Yet, the code works without errors (tested on my system) and introduces some best practices to get you going in the right direction and (possibly) resolve all obstacles.

<sub>² All dates and times in VBA are numbers! Dates are stored as the days between December 31, 1899 and the day you wish to store while times are always stored as decimals which represent a fraction of the day. So, 0.5 = half a day = 12 noon. 0.75 = three quarters of a day = 6 pm. Today's date is May 04, 2016. That is 42,495 days after December 31, 1899. Hence, the `.Value2` for today's date is 42,495.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, but `BoundVal = CLng(IIf(IsNumeric(Arr(i)), Arr(i), 0))` doesn't work for dates, throws a Type Mismatch error still.

Comment: As written in my answer "All dates and times in VBA are numbers". And the line `Arr = Split(cell.Value2, Chr(10))` should ensure that the array is filled with numbers only (using the `.Value2` property and **not** the `.Value` property). But if this answer doesn't help you, maybe someone else can be of help...

Comment: .Value2 didn't make a difference. The MsgBox TypeName() traps I have in my code tell me that Arr(j) is a String, which means `IsNumeric(Arr(i))` is returning false each time and keeping BoundVal stubbornly at 0.

Comment: I discovered that declaring BoundVal as a Date worked as a cheat for now. Would still like to find a way to handle both dates and integers as their proper respective data types. Thanks for all the other good process stuff, I'll be putting that to use.

Comment: If your dates are currently `String` (text) then you need to convert them to real / actual dates first: `MsgBox CLng(CDate("November 13, 2015"))`. That should give you 42321 (as in 42,321 days after December 31, 1899 as noted above). Then you have dates and numbers all in one. Yet, I wouldn't do this conversion in the VBA code. Look at your sheets (the data on the sheets) and convert these "text dates" to actual dates. That would probably be better. Remember: dates in Excel are numbers. So, you can check if a cell contains a date by changing the number format to `.NumberFormat = "#,##0"`

Comment: Unfortunately for that idea, I have multiple dates (and integers) in some cells. So it's all text. That's why I'm using the Split function to begin with.

Comment: I just updated the code and tried to make it work for dates and numbers alike. Since I do not have your file there is no way I could test it and the above is a pure shot in the dark. Anyway, even if it needs some tweaking you'll catch my drift and should be able to make it work. I sure hope this resolves this post and we can close it.

Comment: `CLng(IIf(IsNumeric(Arr(i)), Arr(i), CDate(Arr(i))))` got it working. Thanks again for the help!